# Why do I get 'TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable' when trying to iterate over a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare 2 items in a list that work as the values in a dictionary, but it keeps getting converted to numpy.int64 and I don't understand why.

I've tested for 'valores' type using only the first loop and the second one. In the first I get a a list, but in the second I get numpy.int64.

```
import pandas as pd 
import pprint
.
.
.
questionario = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6]}

for variavel, valores in questionario.items():
  for q_passado, q_atual in valores:
    if q_passado and q_atual != 0:
      if q_atual / q_passado > 0.5:
        print(variavel, q_passado, q_atual)
```

I expected the output to be something like 'a 1 2', etc.

Comment: `valores` holds a pair like `[1, 2]`. `for q_passado, q_atual in valores` tried to take each int and split it into two variables. Maybe instead try: `for variavel, [q_passado, q_atual] in questionario.items():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop for `valores` (`for q_passado, q_atual in valores`) since it is a list of 2 elements that can be accessed by expression `valores[0]` and `valores[1]`. You can fix it by simply change to:

```
import pandas as pd 
import pprint
questionario = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6]}

for variavel, valores in questionario.items():
    if valores[0] and valores[1]!= 0:
        if valores[1] / valores[0] > 0.5:
            print(variavel, valores[0], valores[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake while writing the != 0 conditions. You need to seperate these conditions out otherwise the operator precedence messes the logic.

You can use comprehension to trim it down to a one lines:

```py
questionario = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6], 'd' :[1, 0], 'e': [14,6]}

output = ["{} {} {}".format(k, v[0], v[1]) for k,v in questionario.items() if v[0] != 0 and v[1] != 0 and v[1]/v[0] > 0.5]
```

And the output is:

```
['a 1 2', 'c 5 6', 'b 3 4']
```

Explanation:

```
for k,v in questionario.items()
```

This extracts the key value pairs from your dictionary

```
if v[0] != 0 and v[1] != 0 and v[1]/v[0] > 0.5
```

This bundles up the conditions you wrote inside the loop.

As a result, `k,v` will only contain values that satisfies these conditions.

Finally, this adds the values to a string and wraps them in a list:

```
"{} {} {}".format(k, v[0], v[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the variables to the list. Instead, assign the variables one by one.

```
 OLD: for q_passado, q_atual in valores:
 NEW: q_passado, q_atual = valores[0], valores[1]

 Result:
     a 1 2
     b 3 4
     c 5 6
```